# Changes list values after defined ItemsSource reaches to ItemsSource change

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I know that to use a permanent binding use BindingContext and not use ItemsSource. But I'm a little confused by the case:

```
        List<string> source = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) source.Add("item " + i);            
        var MsgsList = new ListView();
        MsgsList.ItemsSource = source;
        source.Add("new item");
        views.Children.Add(MsgsList);
```

here I appointed `MsgsList.ItemsSource = source` and then add `"new item"` to source. On the idea the `ItemsSource` should contain only five elements, but actually is contains six (includes "new item"). I cann't understand why, when I append the `"new item"` **after** `ItemsSource` definition, `ItemsSource` consists of the item. I think it cann't affect on `ItemsSource`. But why is this happening?

If I make `source.Add("new item")` outsite this method (by `source` defined at the class level) inside another method (by onclick on some button for example), everything is predictable and `ItemsSource` does not contains the `"new item"`

Comment: I don't think that ItemsSource is evaluated until after you add it to the View hierarchy, so at that point the "new item" is already present and included.

Comment: @Jason, you're probably right